# Discussion of $Z(A_4) = \{e\}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, permutations, symmetric-groups

I tried to answer the following question:

> Why does the fact that the orders of the elements of $A_4$ are $1,2$
>   and $3$ imply that $|Z(A_4)|=1$?

My answer: Two cycles commute if and only if they are disjoint. But no combination of $2$-cycles and $3$-cycles in $A_4$ can ever be disjoint since there are only $4$ numbers. Hence the centre must be trivial.

Then I looked at the answer:

If there was $x$ in $Z(A_4)$ of order $2$ then a product with a $3$-cycle would have order $6$.

If there was $x$ in $Z(A_4)$ of order $3$ then a product with a $2$-cycle would have order $6$.

I have two questions about this question:

> (1) Is my proof correct?

and:

> (2) Is it a general principle that if the goal is to show the centre
>   of $S_n$ is trivial one assumes by contradiction it wasn't and then
>   produces an element with order too large to be in $S_n$?

Comment: Your prof looks right to me, except the minor point that "Two ++distinct++ cycles commute if and only if they are disjoint."

Comment: Please paraphrase   your second question again.